# Scraping from Reddit, numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Tags: r, web-scraping, sentiment-analysis

My project consists on analysing data on music albums. I already have a dataframe with information, with this loop I intend to scrape the sentiment from reddit comments, then take the mean out of all the comments relative to an album and insert it by row in the initial dataframe.

```
###Create an empty df to fill with the new values
df = data.frame()
for (i in lista[1:2050]) {
  Sys.sleep(5)

###Scraping the comments
  prueba<- RedditExtractoR::get_reddit(search_terms = lista[i], subreddit = "music",cn_threshold=10)
  
### Getting the sentiment from the comments
sent<- sentimentr::sentiment(prueba$comment, polarity_dt = lexicon::hash_sentiment_jockers_rinker)
  meansent<- mean(sent$sentiment)
  print(i)
 
 databasetodo = rbind(databasetodo, data.frame(meansent, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

  }
```

By using this code I get the message "Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) :
numbers of columns of arguments do not match"

Any help would be very appreciated, I am just a beginner

Comment: What are the dimensions of the two datasets? `dim(databasetodo)` and `dim(data.frame(meansent, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))`

Comment: And potentially, do you want the `cbind()` function instead of `rbind()`

Comment: dim(databasetodo)  [1] 2050   19 dim(data.frame(meansent, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
[1] 1 1 . I tried cbind() before, but it appended multiple columns with the same value, not just one with a different value per row

Comment: I just tried to use your code and the only problem is at line 1, you call the empty data.frame `df` whereas later in your code you are trying to update the data.frame `databasetodo`. I made my own search terms, and with this in mind the code worked.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code? I cannot make it work with your observation